# UCI connections to non universe databases is not allowed

Tags: vbscript, unidata

I need to access unidata database from a server. I tried using vbscript.

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open"Provider=IBM.UniOLEDB.1;Data Source=myunidatadatasourcename;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypassword;Location=D:\info\mydatabase;"
```

uci.config file contains

```
<myunidatadatasourcename>
DBMSTYPE = UNIDATA
network = TCP/IP
service = udserver
host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

But I got an error

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: I know this is WAY late but I recently encountered this problem and resolved it. I've put an answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75294739/rocket-unidata-universe-odbc-unable-to-allocate-sufficient-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75294739/rocket-unidata-universe-odbc-unable-to-allocate-sufficient-memory)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pickwiki.com/index.php/JavaSource has some good Uniobjects troubleshooting tips, though it's obviously java-centric.  A couple of things to check and try are:

1. Make sure you can telnet to 31438 on the Unidata server.  If not,
   it's either not listening (run startunirpcd) or you have a firewall problem.
2. Try creating an ODBC connection and click the test button.  The error messages are more informative.
3. If you have an ODBC connection, try removing the provider info.  It's probably
   not IBM any more, unless you have a really old client.

conn.Open"Data Source=ODBC Alias;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypassword"

4. Check out [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/unidata/) - it's super helpful for this kind of ODBC/OLEDB nonsense.
5. There's some setup involved on the Unidata side to allow SQL statements.  If you want to try a quick test, point the ODBC to $UDTHOME/demo and try "SELECT CITY FROM CUSTOMER" which should run without errors.

Comment: I know this is WAY late but I recently encountered this problem and resolved it. I've put an answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75294739/rocket-unidata-universe-odbc-unable-to-allocate-sufficient-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75294739/rocket-unidata-universe-odbc-unable-to-allocate-sufficient-memory)